# angular, unable to dynamically load custom mat-icon with [svgIcon]="lItem.svgIcon"

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material

Using angular 8, I'm unable to load dynamically a custom svgIcon.

### Description

Into my `component.html` I have

```
      <div *ngFor="let lItem of node.nodeInformationsArray" class="itemDetails" [class]="lItem.cssClass">
          <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="lItem.hasOwnProperty('icon') || lItem.hasOwnProperty('svgIcon')" aria-hidden="false"
          class="material-icons-outlined" [matTooltip]="lItem.tooltip">
          <mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.icon">{{lItem.icon}}</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.svgIcon" [svgIcon]="lItem.icon"></mat-icon>
          <span *ngIf="lItem.txt" class="itemTxt">{{lItem.txt}}</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

In this code **trying to have a common solution** for both [angular material icons](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline) and custom icons, I tried to avoid the `svgIcon` solution and line, but if I specify into the innerHtml of `mat-icon` the path for ng material icons I get errors on console.

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.svgIcon" svgIcon="inverter"></mat-icon>
```

So I tried to add both an `lItem.icon` and `lItem.svgIcon` **which works statically** (with in my case 'inverter' as registrered icon on my `.ts` constructor, which tells me the registering, url, and so on is not the problem here. Note that

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.svgIcon" svgIcon="{{lItem.icon}}"></mat-icon>
```

doesn't work either.

### My dream and hopes

```
      <div *ngFor="let lItem of node.nodeInformationsArray" class="itemDetails" [class]="lItem.cssClass">
          <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="lItem.hasOwnProperty('icon') || lItem.hasOwnProperty('svgIcon')" aria-hidden="false"
          class="material-icons-outlined" [matTooltip]="lItem.tooltip">
          <mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.icon">{{lItem.icon}}</mat-icon>
          <span *ngIf="lItem.txt" class="itemTxt">{{lItem.txt}}</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

working with both custom svgIcons and angular material icons, just by registering my custom icon into my constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can register your custom icons as material icons.

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MatIconModule, MatIconRegistry } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@NgModule({
  exports: [MatIconModule]
})
export class DemoMaterialModule {
  customIcons: Array<[string, string]> = [["hat", "assets/hat.svg"]];
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.customIcons.forEach(([iconName, iconPath]) => {
      iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        iconName,
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(iconPath)
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<mat-icon svgIcon="hat"></mat-icon>
```

To use with a dynamic variable:

```html
<!-- hatName = 'hat' -->
<mat-icon [svgIcon]="hatName"></mat-icon>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-custom-svg-icon) on Stackblitz

**Important to note**

`hatName` has to be a string that corresponds to the custom `svgIcon` **name** and not the path!

Comment: Thx, but registering the icon is not the problem, the problem is that dynamically with `svgIcon="lItem.icon"` or `<mat-icon>{{lItem.icon}}</mat-icon>` it doesn't work

Comment: `lItem.icon` has to be the name of the icon not the path

Comment: your `to use with a dynamic variable` doesn't work with angular material.

Comment: What the value of `lItem.icon`? It will work for you. I have it working on my project

Comment: in my case, `lItem.svgIcon` has the value `inverter` and it doesn't work. but if I replace it with `inverter` as direct value into html it works :-(

Comment: Check the demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-custom-svg-icon)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204995/discussion-between-c-ogoo-and-pipo).

Comment: I have the same problem, if you could solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. I assume that you have a property name icon and then you get it from server back-end following code below:

```
private getIconFromData(dataResult: any[]) {
    dataResult.forEach((folder) => {
        folder.iconAsync$ = CacheService // get resource from cache
              .get(
                  folder.icon, // 'user-profile-icon'

                  // if not found from cache then calling http request.
                  // when get a response, we're gonna cache it to reuse
                  this.httpClient.get(`${baseUrl}/${folder.icon}.svg`, { responseType: 'text' }),
              )
              .pipe(
                  switchMap((resource: string) => {
                      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteral(
                          folder.icon,
                          this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(resource)
                      );

                      return of(folder.icon);
                  }),
                  take(1)
              );
    });
}
```

You iterate each item in data result and set input [svgIcon] for mat-icon as `Observable<string>`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let folder of dataResult">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="folder && (folder.iconAsync$ | async) as icon" [svgIcon]="icon" inline="true"></mat-icon>
</ng-container>
```

For you to imagine clearly a model class

```
export class FolderModel {
    icon: string;
    iconAsync$?: Observable<string> // this is optional property. Just use it on template html
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Typo error `lItem.icon`:

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.svgIcon" [svgIcon]="lItem.icon"></mat-icon>
```

instead of `lItem.svgIcon`:

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.svgIcon" [svgIcon]="lItem.svgIcon"></mat-icon>
```

But still got to have both versions and unable to merge them into one for angular & custom icons as this gives an error if `svgIcon` is set to `search` for example:

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.svgIcon" svgIcon="{{lItem.svgIcon}}"></mat-icon>
```

so as workaround the only way is:

```
        <mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.icon">{{lItem.icon}}</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="lItem.svgIcon" svgIcon="{{lItem.svgIcon}}"></mat-icon>
```

setting custom icon with `svgIcon` property and `icon` to angular one